# Javascript Regular Expression Replace %2F with %21

Tags: javascript, regex, get, encodeuricomponent

I need a javascript/regex to replace %2F with %21

This is so that I can pass forward slashes through a GET parameter after applying encodeURIComponent() to a URL.

When it reaches the server side I'll convert back from ! to /

This isn't an ideal solution, but nothing else seems to work with my rewrite rules.

Comment: If you wanted, it might be simpler just to loop through the string and replace them yourself. Regexes are generally used for more complicated string matching than this.

Comment: would it be more efficient to loop do you think?

Comment: Why loop? Use `replace`. I don't see any issue with using a regex here, though.

Comment: Possibly, although see the answer by @spozun which is a simpler, standard-library way and should work.

Comment: Well, it works for the first / not the ones after that. I'm putting it in a loop now.

Comment: @AmyNeville You can use a regex with `replace` and use the global flag. There's no reason to loop.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, hadn't considered `replace`. That is a better way of doing it.

Comment: I updated it to use regex to do a global replace.  Please don't use a loop!

Comment: I avoided the loop of death! Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have solved this problem and it took a great deal of research as I'm not as talented as some people on here. I thought I'd share the solution anyway.

Essentially the server will prematurely decode %2F as soon as it is used, so you end up with a path that is totally wrong.

What you have to do is replace %2F with %252F at the client side.

```
x = x.replace(/%2F/gi, "%252F");
```

This is the double encoded form of %2F.

So when it reaches the server it prematurely gets decoded to %2F instead of a forward slash.

You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try String.replace?

```
x = x.replace(/%2F/gi, "%21");
```